# Create a variable into the loop "for"

Tags: javascript

I work on a function for create a arrays into a array.

I have a JSON like this :

```
[
    [
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":5},
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm1","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":3},
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm2","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm3","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm4","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ]
]
```

And I want a result like this :

```
[
    [5,4,3,4,3,3],
    [1,0,1,0,0,0]
]
```

This corresponds to the concatenation of occurrences.

I tried with a loop for but it doesn't work.

```
var data = [];
for (var i in chartData) {
    var array = [];
    for (var j in chartData[i]) {
        array.push(chartData[i][j].occurrence)
    }
    data.push(array);
}
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: What does "but it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: perfect use case for filters and reducers.

Comment: You have `[ [5,1], [4], [3,1], ... ]`already, just convert it to the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the result you have to make the output you are looking for:

```js
var chartData = [
    [
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":5},
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm1","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":3},
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm2","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm3","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm4","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ]
];

var data = [];
for (var i in chartData) {
    var array = [];
    for (var j in chartData[i]) {
        array.push(chartData[i][j].occurrence)
    }
    data.push(array);
}

var newData = [ [], [] ];
for (var i in data) {
    newData[0].push(data[i][0]);
    newData[1].push(data[i][1] || 0);
}

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
let arr = [
    [
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":5},
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm1","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":3},
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm2","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm3","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm4","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ]
]

/* this could be done more elegantly */
let l1 = arr.map( (t) => t[0]!==undefined ? t[0]["occurrence"]:0);
let l2 = arr.map( (t) => t[1]!==undefined ? t[1]["occurrence"]:0);

let result = [l1,l2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `map` function to transform the input to **desired** output.

```js
var obj =[
    [
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":5},
        {"data_name":"dn1","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm1","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"1F-27","occurrence":3},
        {"data_name":"dn2","defaut_name":"20-34","occurrence":1}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm2","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":4}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm3","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ],[
        {"data_name":"bm4","defaut_name":"13-02","occurrence":3}
    ]
];

var result1 = obj.map(x=>x[0].occurrence);
var result2 = obj.map(x => x[1] ? x[1].occurrence : 0);                         

var result = [result1 , result2];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support true multidimensional arrays,but you can approximate them with arrays of arrays. To access a value in an array of arrays,simply use the [] operator twice.

```
// Created a multinational array 
var table = new Array(10);
for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
       table[i] = new Array(10);

// Initialize the array
for(var row = 0; row < table.length; row++){
    for(col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++){
        table [row][col] = row*col;
    }
}

// Use the multidimensional array to compute 2*5
var product = table [2][5];   // 10
```